# Is it possible to respec weapon upgrade points?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-2016

I put a lot of points (Raritarium) into some of the early weapons I never found much use for, most notably the Combuster. Are the Raritarium upgrades permanent and can they ever be remove or changed at will?

Answer (score 3):

From a cursory search and given how game mechanics usually work for such a renewable resource, probably not, because it'd be too easy to fund higher-level upgrades by scrapping lower-level ones, just gotta grind for more Raritarium, I guess.

Hope you purchased some of the Raritarium drop-rate boosters...

Comment: As far as I remember, I confirm this.